# Kafka Source-Connector Routing to multiple Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka source connector. How can I route the messages to different topics?

Is there a sink connector to move/copy the message from topic A to B?

Or does the [ExtractTopic](http://staging-docs.confluent.io.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#extracttopic) transform the job?

I don't have an app to use streams..

Answer (score 0):

> route the messages to different topics

RegexRouter does this by modifying the topic name string in the SourceRecord before sending to the producer client. This will not "duplicate" records to multiple topics, however, it is 1:1.

> sink connector to move/copy the message from topic A to B?

MirrorMaker2 is a source connector, but does this, yes. However, within one Kafka cluster, this is what you'd use Streams for.